# Heroku R10 Boot Timeout + Node.js Cron

Tags: node.js, heroku, twitter, cron

I'm trying to host my Twitter bot on Heroku that tweets once every hour. But when I try to deploy, it gives me this error:

```
`Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`
```

I did some Googling and found out this usually happens when you try to specify an explicit port instead of using `process.env.$PORT`, but I'm not specifying any ports in my code, which is basically just this:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
new CronJob('0 0 * * * *', function() {
  //tweet once, once an hour
  runTheBot();
}, null, true, 'America/New_York');
```

where `runTheBot()` makes a few API requests using [Twit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twit).

Interestingly, if I set the cron job to run more often than 60 seconds, say once every 10 seconds ('*/10 * * * * *'), it works fine. It even works if I have it run once a minute ('0 * * * * *').

Here's my Procfile:

```
web: node index.js -p $PORT
```

Is Heroku not compatible with this cron library? Should I be using [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) instead?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the process type in the Profile from `web` to `worker`. I also had to manually scale up the dynos of the workers from 0 to 1 since Heroku set it to 0 by default for some reason.